# How to select combobox item automatically and programatically?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an array of combo boxes, and once each combo box is populated with items, I want the first item to be selected automatically. SO I do this:

```
all_transition_boxes[slide_item].SelectedItem = all_transition_boxes[slide_item].Items[0];
```

but then later I can not change the index anymore if I want to select some other item. It seems that the index is permanently set to zero. I tried to use SelectedItem instead of SelectedIndex but it doesn't work at all. I would appreciate any help.

```
  //populate each combobox with corresponding elements
                for (int i = 0; i < slide_transitions.Count; i++)
                {
                    all_transition_boxes[slide_item].Items.Add("Transition " + (i + 1));


                }


all_transition_boxes[slide_item].SelectedItem = all_transition_boxes[slide_item].Items[0];
```

Comment: What you describe cannot be reproduced and is not true. SelectedItem does work. Show your code that loads the data and sets the SelectedItem.

Comment: please see the updated code

Comment: SelectedItem must point to an _item_, not an index.

Comment: like this: all_transition_boxes[slide_item].SelectedItem = all_transition_boxes[slide_item].Items[0]; yes, it works, but it is again stuck to first item in combo box regardless of what I select manually later.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. It's not stuck unless you call it more than once.

Comment: I mean that I have two items in combo box, and I auto select the first one as above. Then later if I manually select second item, selection still stays on the first one.

Comment: Then you're setting SelectedIndex or SelectedItem somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a sample code to replicate your issue, please check it.

A form with a combobox and two buttons:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Activated="Window_Activated">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="329*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="34*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="154*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="146,78,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="101,185,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="266,185,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Click="button1_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the form´s code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var items = new List<string>();

            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                items.Add("Item" + i);
            }

            comboBox.ItemsSource = items;
            comboBox.SelectedItem = "Item0";
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox.SelectedItem = "Item5";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox.SelectedItem = "Item9";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your `ComboBox` (in XAML) set:

```
SelectedIndex = "0"
```

You can set it as a setter in a style that is applied to all instances of `ComboBox` in your array.

Comment: I don't have it in xaml. everything is created dynamically in c# code

Comment: Ok, then: `all_transition_boxes[slide_item].SelectedIndex = 0;`

Comment: I did it before, but it reproduces the same issue that I have. I can not select any item other than first one.

Comment: How do you populate `all_transition_boxes`?

Comment: System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox transitions_box = new System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox();

Comment: all_transition_boxes[i] = transitions_box;

Comment: That's weird, I think something else is triggered that prevents further selection. :(